Chrome crashing on 24.04 with SIGTRAP and SIGILL errors
Wondering if anyone has any suggestions for troubleshooting - I'm getting sporadic crashes of chrome on 24.04 LTS with chrome crashed with SIGTRAP in __bss_start() and chrome crashed with SIGILL.  I am running the deb version of chrome, as the snap version wasn't able to read my PIV smart card.  It seems to occur when I have my PIV smart card being utilized with the browser/opensc. Occasionally I'll get a system error at the same time, but I haven't been able to reliably reproduce that.
